# Android: How to add play button on YouTubeThumbnailView

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have implemented youtubeThumnailView without any problem.

Currently my thumbnail view looks like this on an android phone:
[image]

But how do i add a play button on the thumbnail view like this https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-c06CilFxXA8/TW3qUN4WTBI/AAAAAAAAAIU/6UaNpVuAt5w/s1600/webView+with+play+button.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to:

1. put your youtubeThumnailView in Layout (ex. RelativeLayout)
2. add Button or ImageView over your youtubeThumnailView

example:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <!-- ImageView or your youtubeThumnailView -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_youtube_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_img_default" />

        <!-- ImageView of your button -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_img_capture" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```